# Derivate using chain rule doesn't work in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, symbolic-math, gradient-descent

I am trying to derive the gradient and hessian for a given function. When i directly do the gradient it works well but when I apply chain rule it doesn't works and throws me an error as below

```
Error using sym/diff (line 70)
Second argument must be a variable or a nonnegative integer specifying the number of differentiations.

Error in EO_a1 (line 12)
dfr = diff(f(x),r(x));
```

My MATLAB code

```
syms x a b const r(x)

const = (a*x);
r(x) = (const - b);
f(x) = (1/2)*(r(x)^2);

gradient = diff(f(x));
gradient;
hessian = diff(gradient);
hessian;

%gradient applying the chain rule
dfr = diff(f(x),r(x));
dfr;
drx = diff(dfr,x);
drx;
```

Comment: Which one is line 70?

Comment: Line 70 is referring to the MATLAB function ```diff``` code. where the second argument cannot be another derived function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not be ideal but you can take the derivative with respect to the function `r(x)` by using the function `functionalDerivative()`. Note that `r(x)` will have to be declared after evaluating the first part of the chain rule. After that the second part of the chain rule `r'(x)` can be evaluated after substituting the symbolic representation/equation for `r(x)` using the `subs()`. Following this the two parts of the chain rule can be multiplied. After this process the result matches the step solution in your first solution by taking the `diff(f(x))` which differentiates with respect to `x` which can also be done by `diff(f(x),x)` for brevity.

```
%METHOD 2: CHAIN RULE%
clear;
syms x a b const r(x)
const = (a*x);

f(x) = (1/2)*(r(x)^2);

%First part of chain rule%
dfr = functionalDerivative(f,r(x));
dfr = subs(dfr,r(x),(const - b));

%Second part of chain rule%
drx = diff(dfr,x);

%Product of parts of the chain rule%
Chain_Rule_Result = dfr*drx;
Chain_Rule_Result
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**